# Sql average time calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, time, average

I'm trying to write a sql query that gives me the average time.

I have 5 columns and multiple entries.

the five columns are taxi-number start-date end-date start-time end-time.

I need to find the average time, times given are in 24 hour format but I also need to account for the difference in start-date and end-date if its there,and i need to group it by taxi number.
input

```
Taxi-Number Start-Date  Start-Time  End-Date    End-Time
4412    8/8/2015    18:06:00    8/9/2015    14:00:00
2223    4/18/2013   19:33:00    4/19/2013   0:40:00
1112    10/20/2013  11:23:00    10/22/2013  8:33:00
5553    5/18/2015   21:43:00    5/19/2015   9:15:00
2222    4/9/2014    0:00:00 4/10/2014   0:16:00
```

output

taxi 4412, average time 20 hours 6 minutes or in any format that accounts for this

Thanks.

Comment: (1) Provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Tag with the database you are using.  (3) Be sure to explain what happens if the start and end dates are not the same.  You will get the question anyway, so you might as well explain why you have split the date/time into two columns rather than a single `datetime` column.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Can you provide sample data and what you've tried so far?

Comment: sample data, using mysql Taxi-Number Start-Date Start-Time End-Date End-Time
4412 8/8/2015 18:06:00 8/9/2015 14:00:00
2223 4/18/2013 19:33:00 4/19/2013 0:40:00
1112 10/20/2013 11:23:00 10/22/2013 8:33:00
5553 5/18/2015 21:43:00 5/19/2015 9:15:00
2222 4/9/2014 0:00:00 4/10/2014 0:16:00

Comment: this is to calculate the time taxis were out on service

Comment: What data types are start date,start time, end date and end time?

Comment: all four separate columns, date and time type                                            
 Data type Format Range
time hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn] 00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999
date YYYY-MM-DD 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31

Comment: "I'm trying to write a sql query"  Where's the query???

Comment: well mate, I tried the datediff thing and all, it didn't work and I am a beginner so I don't know what exactly are you looking for. I'm thankful for any help and it is no problem if you ignore the post.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment...

Start here:

```
Taxi_Number Start_Date          End_Date    
4412        2015-08-08 18:06:00 2015-08-09 14:00:00
```

Once you have that as your structure, see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) ... and then get back to us.